# Canvas HTML5 - Change the background color after image drawing

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I search to change the background color of image after image drawing.

I have a color picker where user can change the color of image background.

```
this.picker.onChange = async (color) => {
    const colorPicked = color;
    this.context.fillStyle = colorPicked;
    this.context.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
}

// ...

// The event call this function when it's ready

buildImageProcess(this.context);

// User can use the color picker to change the background color
```

I want change the font color after the image rendering because the image rendering is too long and user should be able to change the image color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Via CSS

If background is transparent then change the canvas CSS `background-color`.

### Via global composite operation

If you want the canvas pixels set to color then use [`ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) to render only on transparent and semi transparent pixels.

If the background pixels already have a color then that is a problem.

### Via a copy of the foreground canvas

This is the method with the least problems. in effect it creates a second layer (foreground) that you can render over a background (layer)

#### Copy canvas

To copy a canvas (foreground)

```
function copyCanvas(canvas) {
    const copy = document.createElement("canvas");
    copy.width = canvas.width;
    copy.height = canvas.height;
    const ctx = copy.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0); // render canvas to new canvas
    return copy;
}
```

You can also use an [OffscreenCanvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas/OffscreenCanvas) or [`ImageBitmap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmap) though to copy the method is slightly different then above. (ALSO check browser support)

#### Render layers

Once you have a copy of the foreground pixels you can render the background then foreground for the final result

```
this.picker.onChange = async (color) => {
    const ctx = this.context;
    if (this.foreGround === undefined) {  // create copy only when needed
        this.foreGround = copyCanvas(ctx.canvas);
    }
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height); // in case color is semi transparent
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(this.foreGround, 0, 0);
}
```

If you change the foreground pixels, just create a new copy of the changes. Eg in the above example just set `this.foreGround = undefined` before adding the background and the canvas will be copied

Comment: Yes! The third method works! You save me many times, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could easily change the canvas-div's background-color, so it wouldn't actually be part of the canvas drawing. This way you wouldn't need to copy/delete and create existing layers.
If you want to eG download your canvas as png, just add that bg as rect like

```
// draws following behind existing
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
        ctx.fillStyle = canvas.style.backgroundColor;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

working example: https://github.com/BarbWire-1/lineIt or https://line-it.netlify.app/